# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression SQL state: 21000

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble of inserting a subquery on my table named `property_sales`

```
ALTER TABLE property_sales
ADD lotfrontage_mean_norm float8;

UPDATE property_sales
   SET lotfrontage_mean_norm =
       ( SELECT ((lotfrontage - AVG(lotfrontage) OVER()) /
                (MAX(lotfrontage) OVER() - MIN(lotfrontage) OVER())) AS lotfrontage_mean_norm
           FROM property_sales
       );
```

If I try to put `LIMIT 1`, it only has one value. So what should be the correct query? Big thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow eric! if you could edit that sql into a code block would be nice. by the way, that `...lotfrontage_mean_norm = (SELCT...` returns multiple rows hence the errors. i'm not sure what you want to do, could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Why are you using window functions (`OVER()`) instead of `GROUP BY`? `GROUP BY lotfrontage LIMIT 1` is an effective way to achieve this also. Also, I'd suggest using something other than `FLOAT` for decimal values. Use `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC`, or `DOUBLE PRECISION` depending on your precision needs.

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa! Thanks for the warm welcome. Actually this is the result (https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMD17BXlFwY6dMoK2LtOiE-J6AViyE0M2lm5TkAv9f-C3FJLBRONVzXkDszl7yy-A?key=bmNuNTI4UExRajZYMUZZV3daa0dIUzRQTFhIX2Z3) of this query: 

SELECT 
((lotfrontage - AVG(lotfrontage) OVER()) / (MAX(lotfrontage) OVER() - MIN(lotfrontage) OVER())) AS lotfrontage_mean_norm 
FROM property_sales;

which I need to insert to my new created column.

Comment: Hi @JSpratt, thanks for the suggestion I already edit the float data_type into double precision. I will try to use group by. :)

Comment: @crunch4life After reviewing this further, I believe you're getting duplicates because of `lotfrontage - <whatever else>`. If you need to set this for each row, you'll need to use some sort of control structure like a loop or a CTE.

Comment: @JSpratt oh that is new to me using loop or a CTE. but will study later. thanks for the tip.  Btw I'm really happy that someone is helping me on this. Cheers!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT your_table_pk
         , AVG(lotfrontage) avg_frontage
         , MAX(lotfrontage) max_frontage
         , MIN(lotfrontage) min_frontage
      FROM property_sales
     GROUP BY your_table_pk
)
UPDATE property_sales
   SET lotfrontage_mean_norm = 
       (lotfrontage - d.avg_frontage) / (d.max_frontage - d.min_frontage)
  FROM data d
 WHERE your_table_pk = d.your_table_pk
;
```

OR:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT AVG(lotfrontage) avg_frontage
         , MAX(lotfrontage) max_frontage
         , MIN(lotfrontage) min_frontage
      FROM property_sales
)
UPDATE property_sales
   SET lotfrontage_mean_norm = 
       (lotfrontage - d.avg_frontage) / (d.max_frontage - d.min_frontage)
  FROM data d
;
```